# Unity doesn't generate xcworkspace, Podfile using iOS Resolver - macOS Catalina

Tags: unity-game-engine, cocoapods, macos-catalina

I'm trying to build an iOS project in Unity 2019.3.14f1 but when I tried to install CocoaPods using */Assets/External Dependency Manager/Install Cocoapods* it returns a warning:

```
gem install cocoa pods --user-install
WARNING: You don't have /Users/danieoquelis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin in your PATH, 
gem executables will not run

.....
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I went to my terminal which uses *'.zsh'* and I added the PATH in the file *'.zshrc'* and *'.zshenv'* then I did *'source'* to the files and restarted Unity to try to build the project again but it only generates xcodeproject without xcworkspace or Podfile.

I tried to uninstall cocoapods from the terminal and I installed it again and from the terminal the warning doesn't appear and when I do 'echo $PATH' it returns:

*/Users/danieloquelis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/danieloquelis/Library/Android/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin*

I don't know if Unity doesn't read the shell based on *'zsh'* and it only works with *'bash'* I update iOS Resolver, Cocoa Pods, Unity, I don't know what else I can do.

CocoaPods 1.9.3
Ruby 2.6.0
iOS Resolver 1.2.155
Unity 2019.3.14f1
macOS Catalina 10.15

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, I forgot to add ARKit Unity Plugin.